# Load particular CSS file with javascript in a rails app

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using skeljs which loads css file according to the device width. How do I go about doing this in rails. Where my css and javascript files are in their particular subdirectories in the app/assets folder and have specified the paths in the js file. I'm using a template by html5up.net
In the init.js file if set the href to each CSS file as '/assets/stylesheets/file.css' but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using rails 3.0 or above, then you can asset pipeline for storing your js/css files.

You need to add <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> in your layout file for eg. layouts/application.html.erb

Above code will add application.js in your webpage, This file will be compressed and minimized in production mode.

Now in application.js, you can include your different js file

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require util
//= require bootstrap
//= require sessions
```

Same thing can done for css files in application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require_self
 * require_tree .
*/
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
@import "users";
```

for more details about asset pipeline you can follow [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) link